# Testing if two objects are equal

Tags: c#, find, equals

I'm trying to create a find method from scratch to see if two objects are equal given that the results of certain methods are equal, using the Equals method to do so. I know using the Find/Contains methods would be faster, but I'm not allowed use them. The signature of the method is "`static int Find(List c, Coffee x)`" Find seeks `x` in `c` and returns a valid index (e.g., `0`, `1`) if `x` exists in `c`, returns `-1` otherwise. The equals method must be used to determine equivalency. If the passed object isn't equal to an object currently in the list, it is added to the list (the list contains two types of objects that derive from a base class, so the list can store both types). Equivalency is defined by `name`, `cost`, `demand`, `holding cost(h)` and `roasttype(M)` for regular and `name`, `cost`, `demand`, `holding cost(h)` and `minimum quantity(also M)` for `decaf`. Here's what I have so far (it's a lot of code that could probably be written better):

```
class EOQCalculator4
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Create objects and references
        Coffee obv = new Coffee();
        Decaf decafCoffee = null;
        Regular regularCoffee = null;
        List<Coffee> inventory = new List<Coffee>();


        // Prompt user for input and store it as a string
        Console.Write("Enter q to quit or the whole data as a comma delimited string using the following format Name,D,C,D:minQ or R:roast ");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();

        // Loop
        while (!s.ToLower().Equals("q"))
        {
            // Split string up and assign componets to variables
            string[] values = s.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string name = values[0];
            string demand = (values[1]);
            string cost = (values[2]);
            string type = values[3];

            // Check for > 0 and convert to numbers
            float D = CheckDemand(demand);
            float C = CheckCost(cost);
            float M = 0;

            if (type.StartsWith("D:"))
            {
                type = Regex.Match(type, @"\d+").Value;
                M = CheckMin(type);
                decafCoffee = new Decaf(name, D, C, M);
                inventory.Add(decafCoffee);
            }

            else if (type.StartsWith("R:"))
            {
                if (type.Contains("light"))
                {
                    M = 1;
                    regularCoffee = new Regular(name, D, C, M);
                    inventory.Add(regularCoffee);
                }
                else if (type.Contains("medium"))
                {
                    M = 2;
                    regularCoffee = new Regular(name, D, C, M);
                    inventory.Add(regularCoffee);
                }

                else if (type.Contains("dark"))
                {
                    M = 3;
                    regularCoffee = new Regular(name, D, C, M);
                    inventory.Add(regularCoffee);
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("\nError, please enter all lower case \"dark\", \"medium\", or \"light\" next time.");
            }

            else Console.WriteLine("\nError, please enter either \"D:\" followed by a number or \"R:\" followed by roast type next time.");
            Console.Write("\nEnter q to quit or the whole data as a comma delimited string using the following format Name,D,C,D:minQ or R:roast: ");
            s = Console.ReadLine();
        }   // End loop

        // Sort and  display values
        var sortedList = inventory.OrderBy(i => i.Q()).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("\nName \t   C ($)      Demand \t  Detail   Q(lbs.)     TAC ($)      T(weeks) ");
        for (int j = 0; j < inventory.Count; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", sortedList[j].toString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(obv.toStringQ());

    }

#region CheckMethods
    // Data validation methods
    public static float CheckDemand(String R)
    {
        float number;
        while (!float.TryParse(R, out number) || number <= 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter a number greater than 0 for demand: ");
            R = Console.ReadLine();

        }   return number;

    }

    public static float CheckCost(String R)
    {
        float number;
        while (!float.TryParse(R, out number) || number <= 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter a number greater than 0 for cost: ");
            R = Console.ReadLine();

        } return number;

    }

    public static float CheckMin(String R)
    {
        float number;
        while (!float.TryParse(R, out number) || number <= 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter a number greater than 0 for minimum quantity: ");
            R = Console.ReadLine();

        } return number;

    }

 public class Coffee
{
    // Members
    private static float sumQ = 0;
    private static int mcount;
    private float k = 20;
    private float mc;
    private string mName;
    private float md;
    private float q;
    private float mh;
    private float tac;
    private float min = 0;
    private float type = 0;
    Coffee i = new Coffee();

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Coffee)
        {
            bool isNameEqual = i.Name.Equals(this.Name);
            bool isuCostEqual = i.Cost.Equals(this.Cost);
            bool isDemandEqual = i.Demand.Equals(this.Demand);
            bool ishCostEqual = i.h.Equals(this.h);
            bool isMinEqual = i.getMin.Equals(this.min);
            return (isNameEqual && isuCostEqual && isDemandEqual && ishCostEqual && isMinEqual);
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Default Constructor
    public Coffee()
    { mcount = 0; }

    // Full Constructor
    public Coffee(string Name, float d, float c, float m)
    {
        mName = Name;
        md = d;
        mc = c;
        mh = (float).30 * mc;
        type = m;
        min = m;
        mcount++;
    }

    public Coffee(string Name, float d, float c)
    {
        mName = Name;
        md = d;
        mc = c;
        mh = (float).30 * mc;
        mcount++;
    }

    // Copy Constructor
    public Coffee(Coffee e)
    {
        this.mName = e.mName;
        this.md = e.md;
        this.mh = e.mh;
        this.mc = e.mc;
        this.q = e.q;
        mcount++;
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Coffee()
    { mcount--; }

    // Properties
    #region Properties

    public float getMin
    {
        get { return min; }
    }

    public float getType
    {
        get { return type; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return mName; }
    }

    public float h
    {
        get { return mh; }
    }

    public float Cost
    {
        get { return mc; }
    }

    public float Demand
    {
        get { return md; }
    }

    public float getQ
    {
        get { return q; }
    }

    public float K
    {
        get { return k; }
    }

    public float getSumQ
    {
        get { return sumQ; }
        set { sumQ = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    // Methods
    public virtual float Q()
    {
        q = (float)Math.Sqrt(2 * md * k / mh);
        sumQ += q;
        return q;
    }

    public virtual float TAC()
    {
        tac = q / 2 * mh + md * k / q + md * mc;
        return tac;
    }

    public virtual float T()
    {
        float t = (q / (md / 52));
        return t;
    }

    public virtual string toString()
    {
        string a = String.Format("{0,-10:s} {1,-10:f2} {2,-13:f0} {3,-11:f0} {4,-11:f2} {5,-0:f2}", mName, mc, md, Q(), TAC(), T());
        return a;
    }

    public virtual string toStringQ()
    {
        string c = String.Format("\nIf you purchase all of the coffee you will need space to hold {0,-0:f2} of coffee", sumQ);
        return c;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Decaf : Coffee
{
    // Members
    private float k = 30;
    private float min;
    private float q;

    // Constructor
    public Decaf(string Name, float d, float c, float m)
       : base(Name, d, c)
    {
        min = m;
    }

    // Methods
    public override float Q()
    {
        q = (float)Math.Sqrt(2 * Demand * k / h);
        if (q < min)
        {
            return min;
        }
        else return q;
    }

    public override float TAC()
    {
        getSumQ += Q();
        return  Q() / 2 * h + Demand * k / Q() + Demand * Cost;
    }

    public override float T()
    {
        return (Q() / (Demand / 52));
    }

    public override string toString()
    {
        string a = String.Format("{0,-11:s}{1,-11:f2}{2,-12:f0}{3,-9:f0}{4,-12:f0}{5,-13:f2}{6,-10:f2}", Name, Cost, Demand, min, Q(), TAC(), T());
        return a; 
    }
}
```

}

```
// Enumerator
[Flags] enum RoastType { light = 1, medium = 2, dark = 3 }

public class Regular : Coffee
{
    // Members
    RoastType roast;
    private float q;
    private float k = 20;

    // Constructor
    public Regular(string Name, float d, float c, float r)
        : base(Name, d, c)
    {
      int x = (int) r;
      roast = (RoastType) x;
      roast.ToString();

     }
    // Methods
    public override float Q()
    {
        q = (float)Math.Sqrt(2 * Demand * k / h);
        return q;
    }

    public override float TAC()
    {
        getSumQ += Q();
        return Q() / 2 * h + Demand * k / Q() + Demand * Cost;
    }

    public override float T()
    {
        return (Q() / (Demand / 52));
    }

    public override string toString()
    {
        string b = String.Format("{0,-11:s}{1,-11:f2}{2,-12:f0}{3,-9:s}{4,-12:f0}{5,-13:f2}{6,-10:f2}", Name, Cost, Demand, roast.ToString(), Q(), TAC(), T());
        return b;
    }
}
```

}

Assuming I implemented the equals method correctly, where/how would I implement the "`static int Find(List<Coffee> c, Coffee x)`" method?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands your overridden Equals method won't work correctly. Equals tests for reference equality i.e. if two object references point to the same object. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more info on Equals.

If you are just wanting to make sure that the same two coffees (with the same name, demand cost and type) are not added, then  you can perform a simple value check on those fields, something like (method added to your Coffee class)

```
public bool CoffeeIsSame(Coffee c2)
{
    return (this.Name == c2.Name) && (this.Demand == this.Demand) && (this.Cost == c2.Cost) && (this.Type == c2.Type); 
}
```

Your Find method could look something like this:

```
static bool Find(List c, Coffee x)
{
    bool result = false; 
    foreach(Coffee coffee in c)
    {
        result = coffee.CoffeeIsSame(x); 
        if (result) 
        {
             break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

To implement your static Find method, you could add it to your Coffee class. Then you call it like this (using some of your code from your Main method as an example):

```
...
else if (type.Contains("dark"))
{
    M = 3;
    regularCoffee = new Regular(name, D, C, M);
    if (!Coffee.Find(inventory, regularCoffee))
    {
        inventory.Add(regularCoffee);
    }
}
...
```

Hope that helps,

cheers